# Connecting potentiometer with on/off switch to audio board

Tags: potentiometer, 12v

I have a B10K potentiometer with an on/off switch, trying to connect this to an audio bluetooth board (Dayton Audio KAB-215 2x15W).

My question:
The potentiometer has 8 pins an I have a hard time figuring out where to connect the different cables, can't find any suitable diagrams.

To the best of my knowledge I know that I have to run the power and speaker cables through the potentiometer, but in which order?

Any hints or tips is much appreciated!

[image][image: SOLVED - uploaded image for future reference]

SOLVED! Uploaded image above for future reference

Comment: According to the [wiring guide](http://www.daytonaudio.com/media/resources/325-100-dayton-audio-kab-215-quick-start-guide(2).pdf) you need to use connectors 4 and 6. Beyond that, documentation on this board seems to be rather thin.

Comment: Buddy thanks so much for this post I'm was having the same issue but thanks to you picture I'll be on the right track. One question is your pot a 1k or a 10k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t find enough information to talk about the wiring to the board, but I think I’ve figured out your pot.

It looks like a dual-gang pot (two potentiometers operated by the single shaft), typically used for stereo.

The front (nearest to the shaft) and middle plates are the two potentiometers. The middle pins should be the wipers.

The rear two pins are the (probably) push-on-push-off switch.

You should be able to verify all of this with an ohmmeter.

Comment: Thank you @DoxyLover, using a multimeter/voltmeter solved my problem! By measuring the original pot I was able to locate where the wires end up on the board. From there i cut the harness and soldered the wires onto the new pot. 

Works like a charm, only problem is I get some noise/feedback when I touch the metal on the pot. Need to figure that one out.

Thanks again!